# River tamarind needing help

Tags: indoors

I’ve had this tamarind for nearly 5 years now. It will look excellent for about a month and then start dropping leaves. I’ve always been afraid to chop it, but every time I take a little off it thrives. I’m wondering if I can chop it way back at the base and have it grow back. I’m afraid to go too low and kill it completely.

[image: tamarind]

Answer (score 1):

Tamarind trees are massive. I cant see how it can grow anymore. I suspect that it needs a bigger pot.  Also keep puning from the top to make it bush out.